# How to have a Tab control fill the center of a DockPanel in WPF

Tags: wpf, dockpanel

I have a WPF Window with a DockPanel that contains a Menu, a TabControl, and a Status Bar. I can get the Menu to dock to the top and the Status Bar to dock to the bottom, but I can't get the Tab control to fill the area between those two controls.

```
<Window x:Class="MediaCatalog.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediaCatalog"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <Menu Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    </Menu>
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                              BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Height="291">
    </TabControl>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="22">
        <StatusBar/>
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element will fill the `DockPanel` unless you set `LastChildFill` to `false`:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="A" />
        <MenuItem Header="B" />
    </Menu>

    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="22" />

    <TabControl Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
        <TabItem Header="A" />
        <TabItem Header="B" />
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Note that you shouldn't set the `DockPanel.Dock` attached property of the last element.

Also, you don't want to specify a default `Height` for the `TabControl` if you want it to fill the remaining space.

The above sample markup will make the `TabControl` fill the remaining space between the top `Menu` and the bottom `StatusBar`:

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem. I guess I was confused about the order that the controls are listed within the DockPanel. So, if a control is the last control defined in the DocKPanel, and LastChildFill == True, then that control will fill all remaining space in the DockPanel.